# Image preview does not work

Tags: settings, pantheon-files

My photos in local folders aren't showing the miniatures. The option in the configurations window is already on to show the miniatures.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening for all folders and all picture file types? Which Files version are you using?

Try pressing the reload icon on the right of the pathbar

Check that you have the tumbler package installed and also the tumbler-plugins-extra package.

Use gnome-system-monitor or otherwise check that the tumblerd process is running.

A file newly created while the view is showing may not show the thumbnail until hovered by the mouse or otherwise refreshed.